# linux terminal view files on router

Tags: linux, file, view, terminal, router

I would like to know the commands for viewing and navigating files on a router. The router is one in use at home. Can be connected to wirelessly or via Ethernet cable.

I know of ps, ls, grep, dd, sudo, su, and some others, however I don't have the knowledge currently for how to view what files are on devices like routers.

The one in question is a BT Home Hub 5

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to check if SSH server is running on your router? I guess that you will not be able to access the one's filesystem. By default SSH is disabled in the most of network infrastructure devices (routers, switches etc.)

Comment: Ok I'll try that. If the router doesn't have SSH what what you suggest then?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot advice you anything useful... You are trying to access the file system that is not designed for this purposes. You need to hack them; there is no common decision in this case.

Comment: Telnet is likely to be running on one or more devices. How about using the command 'telnetd <device ip> ?